sqlite query works form db viewer but not form python
I run this query from DB browser for SQLite DELETE FROM ticket WHERE ROWID = (SELECT MAX(ROWID) FROM ticket); works fine no errors. Then from python program connection.execute("DELETE FROM ticket WHERE ROWID = (SELECT MAX(ROWID) FROM ticket)") runs with no errors but has no effect. What  am I missing? Help greatly appreciated``
I have been looking at the SQlite explicit row id concept but can't see how it applies to python connections.

Try connection.commit()

That was it - my inexperience. The commit must be explicit when using db browser.Thanks very much

Also you can create a connection with autocommit.
